# Posting JSON with '\/' gets escaped as '\\/'

Tags: c#, .net, json, escaping, backslash

I'm currently facing a problem when posting the following JSON Object:

```
{
    "event": "orders.updated",
    "address": "http:\/\/82.75.163.12\/BiedMeerIntegration?connectionId=545",
    "is_active": true
}
```

The problem with the above is that .NET escapes all backslash characters and posts it like:

```
{
    "event": "orders.updated",
    "address": "http:\\/\\/82.75.163.12\\/BiedMeerIntegration?connectionId=545",
    "is_active": true
}
```

I tried different libraries (like ServiceStack and the Microsoft HttpClient) but they all result in the same error. I don't have control of the REST interface and it specifically accepts the url format stated in the first JSON sample.

I also had a look at the GenericUriParser options in .NET 4 but it seems it doesn't make a difference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee656542.aspx

How will I be able to format the request correctly?

Comment: Why are you escaping the slashes in the first place?

Comment: If the address string *really* has backslash characters in it, then that's the problem and escaping them is what the JSON encoder should do. The string resulting from the literal `"foo\/bar"` has no backslash characters in it at all; the backslash you see is an escape, and the string contains only `f`, `o`, `o`, `/`, `b`, `a`, and `r`. Also worth noting: There's no reason to escape slashes in string literals, but again, if you're getting two backslashes in the JSON-encoded result, then those aren't escapes (as you've shown them), they're actual backslashes that should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your string:

```
{
    "event": "orders.updated",
    "address": "http:\/\/82.75.163.12\/BiedMeerIntegration?connectionId=545",
    "is_active": true
}
```

Is actually already escaped, and in fact is perfectly correct JSON. Note that, both in JavaScript and JSON, escaping the `/` is optional and only required when such symbol comes after `<`, in order to prevent unwanted closing of a `<script>` tag.

The output of your JSON serializer should already look like that (even if those `\/` are not really needed, they are correct). So I don't really understand why you are giving a fragment of already-well-formed JSON to a JSON serializer... which then escapes it again. **If you already have correct JSON, shouldn't you simply write it to the output stream?**

On the contrary, if what you have is the `"http:\/\/82.75.163.12\/BiedMeerIntegration?connectionId=545"` string coming from somewhere in your application's model or services (and not the already-formed JSON fragment as you show it to us), then the problem is such string is already escaped -in JavaScript or JSON, can be any-, and you should first correctly unescape it in its corresponding language before giving it to the serializer. But **don't unescape the JSON fragment above as a whole!**... a fragment of JSON without adequate escaping makes no sense, would be simply *not JSON*.